# Alternating between even and odd in a while loop in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I have been working on couple of lines of code but I can't seem to get it to work. Basically I want to alternate between even and odd table-styles via a while loop. What am I doing wrong?

Seems as though it only loops through the if() everytime.

Thanx!

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    echo "<table id='hor-zebra'>";
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       if(i%2 == 0)
       {
          echo "<tr class='even'>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['departure'] ." ✈ ". $row['destination'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
       }
       
       else
       {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['departure'] ." ✈ ". $row['destination'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
       }
       $i++;
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysql_close($con);

  ?>
```

Comment: 1) Don't duplicate blocks of code when you don't need to. `echo "<tr class='".($i%2 ? 'odd' : 'even')."'>"` would work just fine. 2) If you enabled on-screen errors, you'd notice the problem with the missing `$` right away.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a typo in your `if` condition. It should be:

```
   if($i%2 == 0)
```

You can also save a few keystrokes by just assigning the class name to a variable in the if and else blocks:

```
   if($i%2 == 0)
   {
      $class = 'even';
   }
   else
   {
      $class = 'odd';
   }

   echo "<tr class='$class'>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['departure'] ." ✈ ". $row['destination'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: thanx! Will adopt your way of doing it!

Comment: You could even improve this further using this: `$class = ( $i % 2 == 0 ) ? 'even' : 'odd';`

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the css .nth-child property

```
   tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

[As per W3 example](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd)

Comment: it should if it is not then its the lack of browser not supporting w3 specifications

Answer (score 1):

CSS-Tricks has posted a very very elegant solution to this problem.
It appears like super-reductionist C++ magic. Essentially they do this:

```
<div class="example-class<?php echo ($xyz++%2); ?>">
```

This works in any loop: for, foreach and while.
Modifying the integer gives you larger step sizes, i.e. reset after 3, reset after 4 and so on.

[CSS-Tricks final solution](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/applying-evenodd-classes/)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a '$'

```
 if(i%2 == 0)
```

Should be

```
 if(($i % 2) == 0)
```

Comment: Hahahaha!! Damn I saw that just now when I wrote the code...better go to sleep now! Thanx guys!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line...

```
if(i%2 == 0)
```

...with the following:

```
if($i % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: Thanx!! This is what happens when I'm up late...better go to sleep next time :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be improved further.

```
foreach($post_array as $array => $row) {
    $class = ($array %2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
    echo '
    <tr class="'.$class.'">
        <td>' .$row['title']. '</td>
        <td>' .$row['content']. '</td>
        <td>' .$row['catid']. '</td>
        <td>' .$row['id']. '</td>
        <td>' . '<form action="edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
            <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
        </form>' . '</td>
        <td>' . '<form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
        </form>' . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
```