# how to have differnt content every 3rd iteration of while statment in php

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to create a while statement that will give different results for the 4th and then every 3 after that for columns.

so its going to be iterations 1,4,7,10 etc

Here is what i have

```
$count = $query->post_count;
$i = 1;
$located="";

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

$located.= '<h2 class="gold"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
$located.= $shopaddress.'</br>';
$located.= $opentime.' - '.$closetime.'</br>';
$located.= $shopphone.'</br>';
    if ($i == '1' || $i == '4'){ 
        $located.=".";  
    }else { 
        $located.=", ";
    }
$i++;
```

endwhile;

I was thinking that this would work

```
    if ($i - 1 % 3 == 0){ 
        $located.=".";  
    }else { 
        $located.=", ";
    }
```

but i'm it doesn't return results different results (presumably the math set wrong)

```
if ($i % 3 == 1)
```

this seems to work but i'm not sure why and if it's just a fluke.  how does this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternating between even and odd in a while loop in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112624/alternating-between-even-and-odd-in-a-while-loop-in-php)

Comment: no, no it's not. I have quite a different problem.  I know how to alternate even an odd, this is about every 4th and including the 1st.  DIFFERENT.

Comment: Right, because that's **totally different**.

Comment: thank you for understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close...you just need to take into account order of operations and group your operators - it should be:

```
if (($i - 1) % 3 == 0)
```

Your statement is executing the modulus first, so when $i = 4, you have (4 - (1 % 3)), which equals 3.

Comment: thanks!  Can you tell me what ($i % 3 == 1)  does and why it works too?  (just out of curiosity.)

Comment: Yes, it is the remainder of integers divided by 3. So 7 % 3 = 1.